# Azure Automation Account not using HybridWorker Group

Tags: azure, azure-automation

I'm sure I'm doing something silly here, but I've been trying to get an automation account to use a hybrid worker group. Basically theres a webhook which is triggered when a blob is uploaded, the hybrid worker group would be used to send the file to an on-premise server (fileshare). However the tasks complete successfullly but nothing is shown on the fileserver. When I run

```
$hostname = $env:COMPUTERNAME
write-output "this computer is" $hostname
```

I get the "CLIENT" response which is Azure, whereas when I do a test and specify Hybrid Worker Group I get the name of the fileserver. So it looks like I've missed something to tell the automation account to use the hybrid worker.

Is there anything I need to add to specify "use hybrid worker group"

When I look at the "Jobs" I can see the "Ran on" as Azure, not the hybrid worker group.

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AFAIK it looks like your webhook is running on 'Azure' instead of 'Hybrid Worker'. While creating webhook make sure you select 'Hybrid Worker' for 'Run on' setting as shown in below screenshot. Hope this helps!

[image]

Comment: perfect thanks, the web book was targeting Azure not hybrid worker group.. thanks